# Derived class does not call init

Tags: python

I am trying to understand a certain OAuth2/web2py integration, but some quirks in the python class model are making it difficult for me to grasp. Specifically, I have this web2py controller:

```
def google():
    if 'state' in request.vars and request.vars.state == 'google':
        session.state = request.vars.state
    person = Person("google")
    print person.render()
    return person.render()
```

So we have are using the `Person` class here. The implementation is like this:

```
class Person(Base):
```

No `__init__` is present in the `Person` class. The `Base` class has an `__init__` function:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(
        self,
        hooks=[],
        theme="%(name)s/",
        view="app/generic",
        meta=None,
        context=None
        ):
        from gluon.storage import Storage
        self.meta = meta or Storage()
        self.context = context or Storage()
        self.context.alerts = []
        self.context.content_types = []
        self.context.categories = []
        self.context.menus = []
        self.context.internalpages = []
        self.theme = theme
        self.view = view

        # hooks call
        self.start()
        self.build()
        self.pre_render()

        # aditional hooks
        if not isinstance(hooks, list):
            hooks = [hooks]

        for hook in hooks:
            self.__getattribute__(hook)()
```

So my questions is as follows: If `Person` is not explicitly calling `Base.__init__`, will it be called at all?

Or, to make it more general: will the base class `__init__` function be called if the derived class has no `__init__` function? And if the derived class has an `__init__` function but does not explicitly call the base class `__init__` function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the derived class has no `__init__` function, the parent's class `__init__` will be inherited and called.

If the derived class has an `__init__` function which does not call the parent's `__init__`, the parent's `__init__` will not be called.

Comment: Ok. So `__init__` is just a normal function then. Normal overloading rules apply. The only special thing about it is that it will be called during instantiation of an object, correct?